# Searchkick search function not returning any results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, searchkick, neo4j.rb

I am using Neo4j.rb and searchkick for a ruby on rails app.

I have the following class

```
class NeoUser 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  searchkick

  property :first_name, type: String
  property :last_name, type: String
  property :email, type: String

  has_many :out, :neo_users, rel_class: Following

end
```

In the rails console i do:

```
 NeoUser.reindex
```

and then :

```
result = NeoUser.search "*"
```

I get an empty array back : i.e result.size gives me 0

I do have data in my Neo4j database running on localhost:7000

I have my elasticsearch server up and running on localhost:9200

NeoUser.find_by() does give me correct results, so i am unable to figure out why the searchkick search function fails.

Any ideas?

**EDIT :**

Output of NeoUser.reindex:

```
 CYPHER 36ms MATCH (n:`NeoUser`) RETURN n ORDER BY n.uuid LIMIT   {limit_1000} | {:limit_1000=>1000}
 => true
```

**VERSIONS**

neo4j (5.2.9)

neo4j-core (5.1.6)

elasticsearch (1.0.13)

elasticsearch-api (1.0.13)

elasticsearch-transport (1.0.13)

searchkick (0.9.1)

Has it got something to do with the fact that i have installed elasticsearch version 1.7.2 in my ubuntu machine?

**EDIT 2 :**

I saw that when i create data using the console, the search function is able to return the data.

So i guess searchkick is unable to access my original neo4j database running in my localhost:9200.

but NeoUser.all does return all my data nodes, so how do i tell searchkick to use that specific database, or is there some other issue?

Comment: Hrmmm, maybe...  I'm using elasticsearch 1.6.0 which I installed via Homebrew.  Going to see if I can update...

Comment: Just updated to 1.7.2 and not having any issues...  Could you maybe try using it with ActiveRecord to see if it's a problem with searchkick or with neo4j.rb?

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange.  I'm trying to reproduce locally but it's working for me.  What are your versions of `neo4j`/`neo4j-core`/`searchkick`?

One suggestion is that you might try putting your `searchkick` line below the properties in case it needs to see them to search.

Also, what sort of output do you see when you do `NeoUser.reindex`?  How many `NeoUser` nodes do you have?

Comment: I have edited the question, and NeoUser.reindex does not show me number of nodes (which is 18 by the way (just testing right now)).

Comment: Gotcha.  That looks fine to me.  I just wanted to make sure the `find_in_batches` that elasticsearch was calling in the gem was working.

Comment: It works fine with ActiveRecord sqlite, so i guess the problem is with neo4j.rb

Comment: I saw that when i create data using the console, the search function is able to return the data. So i guess searchkick is unable to access my original neo4j database running in my localhost server.

Comment: `searchkick` should be using the right database based on the model that you put it on.  Did you try moving the call to `searchkick` lower?  Maybe also try calling `searchkick index_name: 'foobarindex'` and `reindex` again to refresh things....

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your comment.  So maybe there's a problem with the `reindex`.  My suggestion in the last comment might help then.  How many times did you try to `reindex`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92282/discussion-between-artemis-fowl-and-brian-underwood).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and it turns out that the I was getting zero results with a 3 character search, but if I input 5 characters I would get results.  I assume this is a default ES configuration.  Maybe this will save someone some time.